# Win App using Background worker process running on Terminal Server goes Non responsive

Tags: winforms, backgroundworker, c#-2.0

There is a Win app tool(C#) running at terminal server which is used to download mails, process the attachment in it and update its UI. Downloading and processing of mail attachments is done using the Background Worker process which also responsible for updating the UI with mails and attachments total and processed count at that instance. There is a timer which ticks to re-initializes the same background worker process after specified duration and look for new mails.

All works fine till the time I am logged in RDC, but when I lock the system (Window key+L) or switch users and comeback to regain the same session the tool is stuck/non responsive, it happens even if I lock and unlock the system instantaneously. I used another process monitoring tool which initially showed child threads getting created and exited periodically but after it is stuck no activity is shown.

I have no clue why is it happening, is window messing is stopped or UI Controls handle are lost or or or....

Following are the chunks of code I am using:

```
private void tmrScheduler_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
        if (bgwMailParser == null || (!bgwMailParser.IsBusy && !objfeMailImportNParse.Is_Parsing))
        {
            bgwMailParser = new BackgroundWorker();
            bgwMailParser.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(objfeMailImportNParse.opLoadCommonData);
            bgwMailParser.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(objfeMailImportNParse.StartMailImport);

            if (HireCraft.Properties.Settings.Default.Close_App_After_Parsing)
                bgwMailParser.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(opCloseApplication);

            bgwMailParser.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(opDisposeWorker);

            bgwMailParser.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
```

below method handles the events raised by bgWorker process

```
private delegate void Del_updateParsedCounter(Int64 del_MailCount, Int64 del_AttchCount);
    private void UpdateParsedCounter(Int64 MailCount, Int64 AttchCount)
    {
        try
        {
            if (lblMailParsedCount.InvokeRequired)
            {
                Del_updateParsedCounter objUpdateParsedCounter = new Del_updateParsedCounter(UpdateParsedCounter);
                this.Invoke(objUpdateParsedCounter, new object[] { MailCount, AttchCount });
            }
            else
            {
                lblMailParsedCount.Text = MailCount.ToString();
                lblAttchSavedCount.Text = AttchCount.ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Assert(false, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I identified solution to issue but forgot that I raised a question here which wasn't answered.

Well issue was the background worker thread declaring a UIControl deep down somewhere in the code.

When a thread creates a UIControl it also registers itself with SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged event which notifies color, theme, screen size changes, system lock/unlock etc. and to respond to which parent thread requires a message pump lacking in background worker thread, the event invoke waits for a (never coming) response causing the application to hang or act non-responsive.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943139 link to Microsoft support explains the same.